# Cocos2d/directC pointer inheritance; adding children vs changing data

Tags: pointers, cocos2d-iphone, addchild

OK so like a lot of us novice codehacks, I've gotten to the point where, through trial and error, I can throw together a relatively fun and reasonably stable game without really understanding WHY a lot of my code works, and I have a poor understanding of pointers and data management. I've tried studying, but since I lack a formal academic background in computer science and have 15 years of experience coding, the introductory stuff is way too easy, and the advanced stuff uses a ton of terminology I don't understand paired with code that I do.

I'm trying to understand why it is that sometimes I can define a new variable, point it at another variable, and then change the pointed data indirectly, and sometimes I can't.  Here's an example where it DOES work as I expect:

```
NSString *myString = [MySingleton sharedMySingleton].singletonString;
myString = @"Hello there!";
[myString retain];
```

By changing the locally defined "myString" i can cause changes to the singleton string.

Here's an example where it DOESN'T work as I expect:

```
HUDLayer *windowBox = shopWindowBox;
[windowBox addChild: shop];
[windowBox retain];
```

In this case, HUDLayer is just an essentially blank file, and "shop" is a menu containing my store, and "shopWindowBox" is an instance of HUDLayer.  If I call the code with [shopWindowBox addChild: shop], it works, but as soon as I try to define a new HUDLayer and point it, it doesn't work.

I understand that I'm doing a very fundamentally different operation, in one case I'm changing the contents of a string, and in another case I'm adding a child.  The conclusion I've come to is "you can't add children to a pointed data", but am I really understanding this correctly, an if so why not?

Answer (score 0):

I found a code error in a different block that was setting its visibility to FALSE.

I was attempting to make the code more plug-and-play by changing "shopWindowBox", "unitWindowBox", and "unlockablesWindowBox" all to be locally defined variable with windowBox, but my "hideUnitWindowBox" and "hideUnlockablesWindowBox" functions were setting the visibility of my shop window to FALSE after populating it.

I guess pointers not only work as I expected, they work BETTER than I expected... I stupidly merged 4 different windows into a single window using pointers.